# Group by row data that has a children property

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I am trying to display a grid with nested rows. My data has a children property with objects similar or almost exactly as the parent one.

I have tried giving some of my columns a cellRenderer property of 'group'.
I have been using getNodeChildDetails, but it seems like this method got deprecated and the new way of doing this is to specify a property on every row called path, which I find to be a pretty weird and ugly approach.

getNodeChildDetails mentioned above does not support any changes inside the row, therefore it is not of good use for me.

is there a method replacement for getNodeChildDetails that would have the same functionality?

All I want to do is group by row some data on whether it has a children property or not.

Comment: If you implement the "weird and ugly" approach, does it work?

Comment: it does, but I would have nested loops, and I might even have nested data of level 3

Comment: Well, that's what nested loops are for.